# EC2 Spot Instance capacity pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I understand that spot instances are terminated if the bid price is exceeded, and that they can't launch if there is no capacity to do so or the instance limit is reached. I've not seen them terminated due to over-subscription before. Used AWS CLI:

```
aws ec2 request-spot-instances --spot-price "0.8" --instance-count 1 --type "one-time" --launch-specification c:\path\to\spot-instance-spec.json
```

The r4.4xlarge linux spot launched successfully in (my) eu-west-1b, then terminated and the status in the spot request is:

```
instance-terminated-capacity-oversubscribed: Your Spot instance was terminated as there is no more unused capacity available in this pool.
```

Does anyone know what this means specifically? Is a pool just the AZ? Is it down to more expensive spots? Is it due to on-demands being launched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Your Spot Instances continue to run as long as your maximum price is
>   at or above the Spot price, there is available capacity for your
>   instance type, and you don't terminate the instance. If a change in
>   the Spot price or available capacity requires Amazon EC2 to terminate
>   your Spot Instances, the Spot request goes into a terminal state. For
>   example, if your price equals the Spot price but Spot Instances are
>   not available, the status code is
>   instance-terminated-capacity-oversubscribed. A request also goes into
>   the terminal state if you cancel the Spot request or terminate the
>   Spot Instances.

Its mentioned here in AWS Doc, and also check for limitation of spot request.For some instance there is a limit beyond that it cant be launched.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-bid-status.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html

Comment: Ok, so the number of spot instance requests in the pool over my bid price has exceed the capacity, not that the price has gone up. No mention of whether a pool is the AZ or not, so I can just relaunch in a different one if this happens?

Comment: Yes first check your spot limit for r4.4xlarge, then in target capacity use that much no. ( if its 1 capacity will be 1 ) and then launch with slightly higher price.

Comment: Thanks, it's not resource limits as they're at about 80 for this instance type now for some batches blue/green deployments.

Comment: @sanath a higher price does not guarantee an instance.  AWS has recently changed something in the spot market thst causes price fluctuations to occur significantly less often, and as a side effect, you can bid higher than market yet not get a machime, because your high bid no longer triggers a demand-driven market shift.

Answer (score 4):

The AWS documentation now has a definition of Spot instance pool:

> Spot Instance pool – A set of unused EC2 instances with the same instance type, operating system, Availability Zone, and network platform.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-instances.html